# Framework that provides tabs/hotkeys/menus for desktop applications for C++

Tags: c++, gui

There are major Java frameworks for building desktop applications - [NetBeans Platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/) and [Eclipse RCP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform). They provide generic functionality that handles menus, toolbars, hotkeys and so on.

I'd like to learn - are there similar frameworks for C++?

Comment: Please make your question more specific, there are too many possible answers. For instance, what operating systems do you target? What is your budget? Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and improve your question, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, I have no need for such specifics, I don't have interest in particular OSes.

Comment: You don't need the resulting program to run on any OS? Or do you mean that the resulting program must run on all OSes, such as Haiku and z/OS?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, all possible options. The same applies to CPUs and phases of the Moon when the program is supposed to work.

Comment: Sorry, no framework works on all OSes, and even less on all CPUs. Please help us help you by defining your needs correctly. Most frameworks work during all phases of the moon, though.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, I never claimed that there are frameworks that run on all OSes or all CPUs nor that I seek for such framework.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) is a portable C++ framework, which implements many standard programming problems. Creating a GUI is one of them and is usually done in the *Qt creator* IDE. Qt is free and open source.

It is pretty well [documented](https://doc.qt.io/), [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-tabdialog-example.html) is a tab dialog example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for **frameworks** "similar" to Netbeans and Eclipse, but written in C++ instead of Java, there are a few alternatives, but probably not as versatile.
For instance, [KDevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/) (I used it for a while to develop in C++, and I found it quite reasonable), [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/), and [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835) for MacOS.

Comment: I was talking about "rich application platform" type of framework that provides boiler plate for desktop applications so that you have no need to write your own tabs/hotkeys/menus functionality.

Comment: @GillBates - Does the first paragraph address the OP?

Comment: KDevelop/Xcode are IDEs, they are advanced editors for developers, not "frameworks".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/).

- It is cross platform.
- It supports many GUI widgets. You can search the [manual](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/) to see what it provides.
- There is a list of [some of the applications built with wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/about/screenshots/).

I also recommend some more C++ [GUI and other tools](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp/blob/master/README.md#gui) that you may find useful.